# Controller multiplication from ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

In my document I have a table cell labeled P/L which is calculated by:

P/L = Sell price * Sell Quantity – Buy price * Buy Quantity

You can see I have started by using some multiplication on my repeating cell item like so

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.TxnId.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.TxnId[i];
        total += (product.Price * product.Quantity);
    }
    return total;
};
```

The problem is I'm wondering how do I select the sell price and sell quantity?  If I can select the sell price and buy price as well at the sell price and quantity I think I can get this to work.  Any ideas?

You can also see I am using sort by for the buy and sell data which loads in also.

Use the output to compute profit and loss for each sell transaction based on the First in First out for Pineapples.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XfRbKe7bNOBn8rGskGyW?p=preview

[image]

below is a picture of what it should look like, I struggling to figure out the P/L column.

Comment: It is also supposed to use the transaction data for each transaction to get the P/L

Comment: you'll need to do these calculations in your controller, since you have multiple *objects* that refer to the same *Symbol*.  As far as angular is concerned, each of these objects is separate, they just happen to share the same Symbol text.

Comment: I changed my code to reflect the calculations on the controller, but still not sure where to go from here. http://plnkr.co/edit/XfRbKe7bNOBn8rGskGyW?p=preview

Comment: that code still won't work;  you are still calling it for every `item`, so there isn't anything to filter, besides the fact that you can't apply a filter in javascript that way.  To do the calculations you want, you would need to consolidate your data so that you have an object that holds the array of price changes, rather than an object for each price change.

Comment: if I am interpreting what you want to do correctly, you actually probably need another data element to track the running total of your transactions.

Comment: Yes that is correct.